# Sonarqube - Fail to execute ES search request error

Tags: sonarqube

```
Our SonarQube Server Version - 5.6.7 (64-Bit). 
Sonarqube Server OS is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. 
MySQL Version- 5.7 
Current MySQL-DB size is - 18GB.
```

**Problem:** Last few weeks on-wards. Few of our sonarqube projects on Sonarqube dashboard issues tab showing all zero issues.

For the same I tired deleting `SONARQUBE_HOME/data/es` folder and rebooted the server. However it works only for few mins. Then again all issues showing zero.

Sonarqube log shows below error, So any suggestions/help for this problem would be helpful.

Error:

```
2018.04.05 16:52:09 ERROR web[o.s.s.w.WebServiceEngine] Fail to process request http://101.102.103.104:9000/api/issues/search?facets=createdAt&ps=1&additionalFields=_all&componentUuids=AV3BEKw6erBW4ICFn1Oe
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fail to execute ES search request '{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":[{"terms":{"project":["AV3BEKw6erBW4ICFn1Oe"]}},{"has_parent":{"query":{"filtered":{"query":{"match_all":{}},"filter":{"bool":{"must":{"or":{"filters":[{"term":{"users":"a.sunil"}},{"term":{"groups":"Anyone"}},{"term":{"groups":"sonar-users"}}]}},"_cache":true}}}},"parent_type":"authorization"}}]}}}},"aggregations":{"issueCreatedAt":{"min":{"field":"issueCreatedAt"}}}}' on indices '[issues]' on types '[issue]'
    at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxySearchRequestBuilder.get(ProxySearchRequestBuilder.java:47) ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.es.request.ProxySearchRequestBuilder.get(ProxySearchRequestBuilder.java:35) ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndex.getMinCreatedAt(IssueIndex.java:514) ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndex.getCreatedAtFacet(IssueIndex.java:466) ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndex.configureStickyFacets(IssueIndex.java:427) ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.index.IssueIndex.search(IssueIndex.java:234) ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchAction.doHandle(SearchAction.java:301) ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.issue.ws.SearchAction.handle(SearchAction.java:288) ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at org.sonar.server.ws.WebServiceEngine.execute(WebServiceEngine.java:107) ~[sonar-server-5.6.7.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor384.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_162]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(JavaMethod.java:425) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:292) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvoker.java:44) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:70) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
    at rubyjit.Api::JavaWsController$$index_E9F115BCB78D2E226E3015CDA52C1912485D30D07277985.__file__(/opt/sonarqube-5.6.7/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/java_ws_controller.rb:34) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
```

Comment: The current version of SonarQube is 7.0, and the current LTS is 6.7.2. You're going to have a hard time getting support for versions older than that. You should consider upgrading at your earliest convenience.

Comment: Upgrade soon we will plan and do it, Currently is there any workaround available for the same?

Comment: Hi Team, Upgrade to latest LTS version might take some time. As still we didn't get the confirmation from all our stackholders. So could tell me any other workaround to resolve the issue. This would help us a lot.

Comment: If i increase the following to -Xms4g and -Xmx4g in sonar.properties file. Will it work? Plz let me know. sonar.search.javaOpts=-Xms512m -Xmx512m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError